# Swift4 - How to apply asynchronous function each element of array

Tags: ios, swift, loops

**[edited]**I have a for loop, it supposed to go through every step in the loop from top to bottom one by one and go back to the top and repeat the steps again. However, it did not go to the last step (which is a function), it go back to the first step from the middle, getting all the parameters, and after finishing looping all the steps from top to middle, it then go to the last step, and run the function several times, but only using the last parameter got from the previous step.

I tried to put the last step (the function) outside the loop, but in the loop the last parameter will overwrite the previous ones and the function will only use the last parameter.

The loop code which used to get the products information and add them to cart:

```
@IBAction func btnReorderTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !isReorderDisable {

        let orderItem = orderDetail.items

        func addToCart() {
            viewModel.addCartItem(success: {
                print("product added")
            }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                self.showAlert(errorMessage)
                print("fail")
            })
        }

        var results: [CartItemData] = []

        for item in orderItem {

            let cartItem = CartItemData()

            cartItem.sku = item.sku
            cartItem.qty = item.qtyOrdered
            cartItem.name = item.name
            cartItem.price = item.price  

            results.append(cartItem)  
        }
        for i in 0...1 { // test two sets of value in results[i]
            viewModel.cartItem = results[i]
            addToCart()
        }
    }
}
```

The code for function “addCartItem”:

```
/**
 Add new item to existing shopping cart
 */
func addCartItem(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (_ errorMessage : String) -> Void) {
    cart.cartItem = cartItem
    cart.cartItem?.quote_id = "\(CartInfo.getCartID() ?? 0)"

    if ReachabilityUtil.shareInstance.isOnline() {
        beforeApiCall?()

        // IF CART NOT CARTE, CRATE THE CART AND RETRY CART ITEM ADD
        createCartData(success: { (_) in
            self.cart.cartItem?.quote_id = "\(CartInfo.getCartID() ?? 0)"
            // CHECK CART LIMIT BEFORE ADDING NEW ITEM INTO CART
            self.checkCartLimit(success: { (checkLimit) in
                if let limitErrors = checkLimit.limit_errors {
                    for limitError in limitErrors {
                        switch limitError.typeLimit {
                        case .cartItemAndTotalLimitExcced, .cartItemLimitExceed, .cartTotalLimitExceed:
                            failure(limitError.message)
                            return
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ADD ITEM TO CART
                CartApiManager.sharedInstance.doAddCartItem(data: self.cart.toJSON(), completed: { (apiResponseHandler, error) in
                    self.afterApiCall?()

                // print("cartData-", self.cart)

                    if apiResponseHandler.isSuccess() {
                        // UPDATE CART DATA IN LOCAL DB
                        self.getCartData(success: { (_) in

                        }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                            print("\(errorMessage)")
                        })

                        // UPDATE CART SUMMARY DATA IN LOCAL DB
                        self.getCartSummary(success: {

                        }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                            print("\(errorMessage)")
                        })

                        success()
                    } else {
                        failure(apiResponseHandler.errorMessage())
                    }
                })
            }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                self.cart.cartItem?.quote_id = "\(CartInfo.getCartID() ?? 0)"

                // CHECK LIMIT MAY BE FAILURE ON FIRST STAGE, SO WE ALLOWED TO ADD ITEM INTO CART
                CartApiManager.sharedInstance.doAddCartItem(data: self.cart.toJSON(), completed: { (apiResponseHandler, error) in
                    self.afterApiCall?()

                    if apiResponseHandler.isSuccess() {
                        // UPDATE CART DATA IN LOCAL DB
                        self.getCartData(success: { (_) in

                        }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                            print("\(errorMessage)")
                        })

                        // UPDATE CART SUMMARY DATA IN LOCAL DB
                        self.getCartSummary(success: {

                        }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                            print("\(errorMessage)")
                        })

                        success()
                    } else {
                        failure(apiResponseHandler.errorMessage())
                    }
                })
                return
            })
        }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
            failure(errorMessage)
        })
    }
}
```

The expected print message should be:

```
sku- xxxxxx
final- CartItemData {
    sku = xxxxxx;
    qty = 1;
    name = nnnnnn;
    price = 100;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
cartData- CartItemData {
    sku = xxxxxx;
    qty = 1;
    name = nnnnnn;
    price = 100;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
product added
sku- yyyyyy
final- CartItemData {
    sku = yyyyyy;
    qty = 1;
    name = mmmmmm;
    price = 200;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
cartData- CartItemData {
    sku = yyyyyy;
    qty = 1;
    name = mmmmmm;
    price = 200;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
product added
```

There should be two items added into cart. But,

The actual print message is:

```
sku- xxxxxx
final- CartItemData {
    sku = xxxxxx;
    qty = 1;
    name = nnnnnn;
    price = 100;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
sku- yyyyyy
final- CartItemData {
    sku = yyyyyy;
    qty = 1;
    name = mmmmmm;
    price = 200;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
cartData- CartItemData {
    sku = yyyyyy;
    qty = 1;
    name = mmmmmm;
    price = 200;
    product_type = ;
    quote_id = ;
}
product added
```

So the final added item is only the second item.

Please anyone can tell me how to apply the asynchronous function "addCartItem" to each element in the array "results"? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you understand what "asynchronous" means?

Comment: FYI - the line `let cartItem = CartItemData()` needs to be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Might want to start here, read this and the next article in the series: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: @matt, I'll check the link, thanks

Comment: @matt, I read the articles, but I thought the last asynchronous function should be the last one to run but still inside the loop, however, it even run after the loop. If the steps are given number "1,2,3,4,5,6", the last function let's call it "6", then what I want is in sequence "1,2,3,4,5,6--1,2,3,4,5,6,--.....", but actually it is in sequence "1,2,3,4,5,--1,2,3,4,5,--....6,6,...,6,6" I don't know how to let the asynchronous function run before the other steps go into another round of loop.

Comment: Yes, I should clarify that when you have multiple asynchronous blocks, everything happens later and in no particular order.

Comment: You can be notified after all the loop iterations  complete, but even so you cannot know in what order each one happens.

Comment: @matt, thanks. But I still don't know how to avoid the async issue. I'm trying to use "DispatchGroup" to see if I can force the async function to run before the loop go into the next round.

Comment: But the async function takes time. Suppose it takes one minute. If you could hold everything up before the loop continues, then if you loop ten times, it takes ten minutes! The whole idea of async is that you _do not wait_. You should perform all the iterations and just accept that the async callbacks can come at any time in any order.

Comment: @matt, understood, thanks. But my issue now is I just want the "addCartItem" function to run every time the loop go one round, not after the loop finished running. Do you know whether "DispatchGroup" will do that? Or should I collect all the results from the loop and then pass all the datas to the "addCartItem" function? Thanks

Comment: By right I should get all datas for several items, and then add all items to cart. But now after the loop the last item data will overwrite the previous ones and pass to the "addCartItem" function, so what I get is added 10 "last item" into the cart instead of 10 "different items" into the cart (if there are 10 items). What I want is get one item data, run "addCartItem" function to add to cart, get another item data, run "addCartItem" function again to add the second item to cart, add so on...

Comment: Now I'm thinking to append all datas from the loop into json array (maybe) and then pass them one by one into the "addCartItem" function.

Comment: "Or should I collect all the results from the loop and then pass all the datas to the "addCartItem" function?" Exactly. Just do your loop and accumulate the results. Then after that (you can arrange this using DispatchGroup) do something with those results. Either that, or write `addCartItem` so that it doesn't do a mere append, but slots each data into the right place when it arrives.

Comment: Also remember _networking can fail_. Some or all of your async functions might _never_ arrive. You have to accept that you get whatever you get in whatever order you get it.

Comment: @matt, OK, I'll try these methods. Thanks

Comment: Hi @matt, I edited my post. I tried to append all the "cartItem" information into an array "results", but I failed to apply the asynchronise function "addCartItem" to each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

- Since the `viewModel.addCartItem` has an api call that use the `cartItem` model in that API call, so the solution will be by passing the `cartItem` to the `addCartItem` function as a separate parameter.
- This is because the api call is happening async, so that's why they all see the last cartItem that you assigned to your viewModel.

It should work well if you changed the way you call the addCardItem function to:

```
func addCartItem(_ cartItem: CartItemData, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (_ errorMessage : String) -> Void) {
   // here user cartItem instead of self.cartItem
}
```

and you should replace the call for:

```swift
viewModel.addCartItem(success: {
            print("product added")
            }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                self.showAlert(errorMessage)
            print("fail")
            })
```

by:

```swift
viewModel.addCartItem(cartItem, success: {
            print("product added")
            }, failure: { (errorMessage) in
                self.showAlert(errorMessage)
            print("fail")
            })
```

Comment: Hi Hossam, thanks for your answer, I tried but it give error message saying "missing argument for parameter #1 in call in the line: "viewModel.addCartItem(success: {"
and suggestion  'addCartItem(_cartItem:success:failure:)' declared here' in line
func addCartItem(_ cartItem: CartItemData, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure:

Comment: Hi Hossam, thanks, I tried the updated code, the error gone, but still the same async issue. The code seems working in the same way as original code.

Comment: Is it possible to store each result of the parameters （cartItems）in the for loop (into a json array maybe?) and then use the stored results to run the "addCartItem" function？ Thanks